# What is this schematic symbol? A transformer?

Tags: schematics

I found this schematic symbol I've never seen before. I think it's some type of transformer? Please let me know what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is a transformer, the loops indicate that the inductors are tied together magnetically, the numbers probably indicate wires or pins numbers on the transformer.

Comment: I don't think it's a standard symbol, though.

Comment: The ovals in the center of the symbol may indicate that this is a transformer wound on a toroidal core.

Answer (score 0):

With My point of view, it's a transformer wound around a toroidal core and for the number 6 0 and 5 0, I guess it shows the numbers of turns.
Which means:

The top one has 6 turns, it might be on both sides I guess, but the starting point is from the down where 0 is written, then ends at the top where 6 is written.

Same for the second one , the only difference is the top one have six (6) turns, while the down has five(5) turns.